# API 17: how to store in a array List<List<Integer,Double>> Android studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm using google-vision for a project and in particular now I'm using [this java class](https://gist.github.com/tiraeth/1306602) inside my code.I'm doing some stuff with frame detected and now I'm running into this problem:
If I use :

```
 List<Map<Integer, Double>> peak = PeakDetect.peak_detection(Greenlist,delta, indices);
```

and I would to separate Integere and Double,how could I do that?
My tester phone support API 17 like minSdkVersion and I can't use command like:

```
List<List<Integer>> indexes = peaks
         .stream()
         .map(p -> p.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(indexes.get(0)); // maxima list output = [0, 5]
System.out.println(indexes.get(1)); // minima list output = [3]
```

Is there another way to split or separate and store all keys in a new string?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you need a flat List of all the indexes or you need to safe the nested structure?

Comment: I'm using that List every time face is detected. I would to store keys in another box to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe that this is what you need.

```
List<List<Integer>> indexes = new LinkedList<>();

for (Map<Integer, Double> map : peaks) {
    indexes.add(new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()));
}
```